# Raspbmc is freezing while navigating in the menu

Tags: raspbmc, kodi

I recently installed raspbmc on my rpi model B.

My Problem: When navigating in the menu it sometimes just freezes, but ssh connection works fine. Before freezing there was about 60% cpu usage and after only ~3% from the xbmc task. The log file doesn't display any errors, but it still receives and logs cec signals. Also one time it froze while updating the library, the updating was still in progress even though the screen got stuck.

I have only watched about 2 hours yet and I had to restart one time because the video ran in slow motion (I don't know if I accidentally activated a slowmo function)
This happened with Amber and Bello and I think with the default one too, but I am not sure, I can tell you later.

Previously I ran a node server on it and for about two weeks motion, without a single crash. So I doubt it is a power problem.
Has anyone had the same issues? Or does someone have a solution for me?

Comment: It used to happen with me before and the problem was insufficient power supply. When you use HDMI and more CPU, you use much more current then server mode.

Comment: But to give you another solution, try to change the SD card.